# Why the simplest Hopf surface is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

The original Hopf surface, is the
quotient of $\mathbb{C^2}-0$ by the infinite cyclic group, generated by the homothety

$(z_1,z_2)\rightarrow(\frac{1}{2}z_1,\frac{1}{2}z_2)$.

All books I read claim it is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^3$, but why?

Comment: Think in terms of polar coordinates, $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}\cong\mathbb{R}_+\times S^3$.

Comment: @Thorgott thanks a lot.